# Benchmarking in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to add some benchmarks using `criterion` package.
I added to `package.yaml` file these lines:

```
benchmarks:
  hw4-bench:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         bench
    ghc-options:
      - -eventlog
      - -threaded
      - -rtsopts
      - -with-rtsopts=-N6
      - -O2
    dependencies:
      - hw4
```

Also I created `bench/Main.hs`.
But when I use `stack bench` command I get a message with an error:

```
Running 1 benchmarks...
Benchmark hw4-bench: RUNNING...
benchmarking perimeter/strict perimeter of 100 points
time      Completed 2 action(s).
terminateProcess: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

Code that I test is pure. Why do I have `permission denied` error? Also if I run by myself `bench.exe` file in `.stack-work` I don't have any problems. What am I doing wrong?

*UPD*:
After updating `stack` to version `2.5.1`, error `<stderr>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)` comes, but `chcp 65001` solves it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like  people run into this `process` error when used on non-utf-8 consoles ([source](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5014))

Can you try running `chcp 65001` and then `stack bench`? We can at least rule this out as a factor.

*edit*
if `chcp 65001` works, you can set the console to utf-8 permanently, as detailed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8/1435645#1435645)

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Stack is the one using process. The current version of stack is 2.5.1, which [uses](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/v2.5.1/stack.yaml#L1) stackage lts-14.27, which [contains](https://www.stackage.org/lts-14.27) process-1.6.5.0, which contains the fix (according to [this source](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5014#issuecomment-535868115))

So, if you upgrade to stack `2.5.1`, this problem *should* be fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I upgraded ```stack``` to version ```2.5.1```, but now if I run ```stack bench``` without ```chcp 65001``` before I have another error:
```<stderr>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)```
If I run ```chcp 65001``` before, there are no problems.
I'm wondering if there are other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: (also I am new to stackoverflow - should I post this problem as another post or it's okay to leave it as a comment?)

Comment: As for stackoverflow protocol, if we find a better solution, I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: So it looks like process was actually hiding the real error here. When the process crashes, `process` (the library) would print a message about not being able to terminate it. As upgrading our infrastructure didn't fix the underlying unicode problem, we can either use `chcp`, or try upgrading our project's stackage version, and packages (presumably criterion).

It [seems](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/18332#note_283181) some things have been fixed on ghc-8.10.1, for which you could use stackage `nightly-2021-01-13`.

Comment: Thank you! But actually I don't fully understand, why I have this error at all? I have no non-unicode symbols in my code and in the path too. Is it only because I'm a user of the Russian Windows and console is "russian"?

Comment: Yeah I think windows console code pages map their 256 characters completely differently for non-utf-8 languages, and I guess `text` is trying to decode if as utf-8 under the hood somewhere.

This answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1435645) (setting utf-8 as default on windows) looks like it would be the best solution, if it works. I really can't think of a downside.

Comment: Yes, checking the ```Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support``` box helps. But I'll prefer to use chcp command instead of it, because of problems it can cause (now I don't see them but who knows..)